# CALL in windows does not wait for a batch to finish

Tags: windows, scripting

I have a Master batch which calls the 2 sub-batches. I would like to run Batch 2 only when Batch 1 completes. But Batch 2 starts running automatically after 60 min.
Below is what i have in the Master batch

```
 CALL C:\Batch1.bat
 CALL C:\Batch2.bat
```

Comment: Is "run automatically after 60 min" the current behavior or the expected behavior? Because I see nothing in the code that specifies "60 minutes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `CALL`:

```
C:\Batch1.bat
C:\Batch2.bat
```

Now it will wait for `Batch1` to finish before starting `Batch2`.